# changing model property value is changing the same property in other object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

im new to vue , i want user to be able to add some specific social media links to the page and edit some properties like it's text

i have 2 objects in my `data`  , `models` and `defaults`

defaults contains selectable option for social media links and their initial values

basically i copy the default value into models and let the user customize the model via inputs

```
 data () {
      return  {

            models : [] ,
            defaults : {

                twitter : { id : null , placeholder : 'my twitter' , icon : 'twitter'  , text : null  , 'link' : null } ,
                instagram   : { id : null , placeholder : 'my instagram'  , icon : 'instagram' , text : null  , 'link' : null } ,
                tiktok   : { id : null , placeholder : 'my tiktok'  , icon : 'tiktok' , text : null  , 'link' : null } ,

            } ,
      }
    } ,
```

so there a select menu for user to select which social he wants to add to the page

```
Select : 
<ul >
  <li v-for="(social, index ) in defaults" :key="index"> 
     <a @click="appendSocial(index)">
       {{ index }}
     </a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

here is my `@click="appendSocial(index)"` function

```
appendSocial(type){
    let typedefault = this.defaults[type];
    this.models.push(typedefault)
},
```

and finally i show my models to user and provide an input for editing it's text via `v-model`

```
<div v-for="(model, index) in models" v-bind:key="model.id">

    <a class="button-preview">
        {{ model.text === null ? model.placeholder : model.text }}
    </a>
   
    <label>Text</label>
    <input type="text"   v-model="model.text"  :key="index" :placeholder="model.placeholder">

</div>
```

so here is the problem , for some reason changing the `models` properties will change the same property in `defaults` ... and changing `defaults` properties will change the same property `models` !!

like if i add a twitter menu to the page and change it's text (model.text) to `abc` via v-model ... it will also change `defaults.twitter.text` to `abc`

to better demonstrate the problem i've added some console log to my appendSocialfunction

```
    appendSocial(type){
        let typedefault = this.defaults[type];
        console.log(`-------- default object for ${type} -----------`);
        console.log(typedefault);
        this.addElement(typedefault);
    },
```

here is the result

[image]

1 - i've selected a twitter link and added to my models  , you can see `defaults.twitter.text` is `null`

2 - i've change my `model.text` (i suppose it would be `models[0].text`) to `abc`

3 - i've added another twitter link to my page ... this time `defaults.twitter.text` is also `abc`

also changing defaults properties will effect all the models the has been getting their value from that default object

like if i change the `defaults.instagram.text` to `xyz` all my models which have got their initial values from `defaults.instagram` will also change their text to `xyz`

it's like they are referencing each other , but i haven't passed the value between 2 objects by reference

im not sure what's happening here and how can i prevent this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because

```
    let typedefault = this.defaults[type];
    this.models.push(typedefault)
```

Is storing the reference to the object into your this.models array. And so if you mutate the element, you're by default changing the base object. A quick and dirty way of doing a deep clone is the following.

```
let typedefault = this.defaults[type];
let clonedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(typedefault));
this.models.push(clonedObj)
```

Note: Lodash library does have a proper deep clone functionality.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-clonedeep-method/

Comment: thanx or maybe i can create a new object on fly and set it's key:vlue from default object (via for loop so it wont be a copy/reference ) ?

Comment: if you're going to do that, you might as well use the clonedeep functionality from lodash, it would do exactly the same thing.